# Convert flextable to grobTable

Tags: r, gridextra, officer

is there any way to convert a regulartable or a flextable to a graphical object, maybe to a grobTable, so that it can be used later by the gridExtra package (eg. with the method grob.arrange) to arrange more elements in a slide easier?
grid.arrange accepts only grobs as input parameters. It works with ggplots but not with regulartables/flextables.
Thank you!

Comment: that's a very good idea. No promise but I can try an implementation (but not before few months to be realistic...)

Comment: It would be great! Thank you!